# how to store two field value in one mysql field in wordpress custom

Tags: php, wordpress

this is my array code to store value in the data table.
I want to store four fields value in one MySQL field

i need to store answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4 in answer row

it's shown an error:- wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. Unsupported value type (array). Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 4.8.2.)

this is my array code

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    $answer1=$_POST['answer1'];
    $answer2=$_POST['answer2'];
    $answer3=$_POST['answer3'];
    $answer4=$_POST['answer4'];
    $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'pte_quiz';
    $wpdb->insert(
      $table_name2,
      array(
        'answer' => array('answer1' =>$answer1, 'answer2' =>$answer2, 'answer3' =>$answer3, 'answer4' =>$answer4),
        'uid' => $uid,
        'user' => $user )
        );
        echo "Your answer successfully submited!!!";?><br>
        Your Answer is <?php echo $answer;
exit;
}
```

Comment: Put the answers in one string with appropriate seperator like $str = $ans1.','.$ans2.','...... ;  then insert the str, in the reterival use explode method to get answers in array.

Comment: @Hardood, Your method is not recommended that much. What if the separator we used is there in the answer itself? On explode, it will break the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    $answer1=$_POST['answer1'];
    $answer2=$_POST['answer2'];
    $answer3=$_POST['answer3'];
    $answer4=$_POST['answer4'];
    $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'pte_quiz';
    $wpdb->insert(
      $table_name2,
      array(
        'answer' => json_encode(array('answer1' =>$answer1, 'answer2' =>$answer2, 'answer3' =>$answer3, 'answer4' =>$answer4)),
        'uid' => $uid,
        'user' => $user )
        );
        echo "Your answer successfully submited!!!";?><br>
        Your Answer is <?php echo json_decode($answer,true);
exit;
}
```

We can simply convert the answers array into a JSON string and store that into database. Later when we need to use the stored value, we can simply `json_decode()` it and get the desired array.